# How to access clojure reagent atom map variable?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I am new to Clojure and Reagent. Kindly tell how to print the variable first inside the atom variable contacts?

(def app-state
  (r/atom
         {:contacts [{:first "Ben" :last "Lem" :middle "Ab"}]}))

Answer (score 2):

**First of all:** the [reagent tutorial](https://github.com/jonase/reagent-tutorial) is a really good place to start. It even gives you examples to solve exactly this problem.

Since reagents `atom` can be treated just as a regular Clojurescript atom, you can use all your normal sequence operations. Keep in mind that in order to access the current value, you have to dereference the atom via `@`.If you really just want to access the first `:first` in your atom:

`(:first (first (:contacts @app-state)))` or `(get (first (get @app-state :contacts)) :first)`

Or, if you think it's more readable

```
(-> @app-state
    :contacts
    first
    :first)
```

I guess what you might want to do is define a few functions to make the access more easy such as:

```
(defn get-contacts!
  "Returns the current vector of contacts stored in the app-state."
  []
  (:contacts @app-state))

(defn get-first-names!
  "Return a vector of all first names in the current list of contacts in the
   app-state."
  []
  (mapv :first (get-contacts!)))
```

Please keep in mind that in **reagent** (and in general really) you might want to dereference that atom as fiew times as possible, so look for a good place to dereference it and just use regular functions that operate on a simple sequence instead of an atom.

Still, I would really suggest you go read the aforementioned [reagent tutorial](https://github.com/jonase/reagent-tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concise way to access the value that you are looking for using Clojure's [(get-in m ks)](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in) function:

```
(get-in @app-state [:contacts 0 :first])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an extra, you may see this often written as

```
(->> @app-state
     :contacts
     (mapv :first)
     first
```

and it's useful to understand what's going on here.

`->>` is a macro called thread-last which will re-write the code above to be

```
(first (mapv :first (:contacts @app-state)))
```

Thread last is a bit weird at first but it makes the code more readable when lots of things are going on. I suggest that on top of the reagent tutorial mentioned in the other comments, you read [this](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/11394651).

Answer (score 0):

`@app-state` will give you whatever is inside the r/atom and `(:first (first (:contacts @app-state)))` will return the first element and `(println (:first (first (:contacts @app-state))))` will print output to the browser console (so you need to have the developer tools console open to see it).

Note that for `println` to output to the browser developer tools console you need to have this line in your code:

```
(enable-console-print!)
```